# Overriding default wrapper name in carouFredSel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

As a newbie to caroufredsel, I am trying to override the default wrapper name in for the carousels using a dynamic count.

However, the carousel rendered only has the default caroufresel_wrapper. Whereas my javascript is trying to get caroufredsel_wrapper0, caroufredsel_wrapper1, caroufredsel_wrapper2 for 3 carousels on the same page. I find it amusing that it will not get overridden.

My code for carousel creation is here

```
$('.carousel-content').carouFredSel({
        circular: false,
        infinite: false,
        auto: false,
        align: 'left',
        width: 940,
        height: 323,
        scroll: 1,
        wrapper: { element:'div',
        classname: 'caroufredsel_wrapper.concat(carousel_count)'},
        items: 4,
        onCreate: function() {
        $('#xy.concat(carousel_count) >       .caroufredsel_wrapper.concat(carousel_count)').css('float','left');
    }
  });
});
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? and who is this caroufredsel guy? a link to the plugin/extension/library will help.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information. [link](http://dev7studios.com/caroufredsel-old/configuration.php)  is the URL of the plugin. ([link]https://github.com/gilbitron/carouFredSel). So, I am trying to get multiple carousels on the same window with different wrapper names and prev and next buttons that work as a way to scroll through the carousel. The default wrapper name is caroufredsel_wrapper and I am trying to override it as shown.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation does not make it explicit, but the `carouFredSel` accepts two parameters: `(options, configs)`. The wrapper makes it part of the configs parameter. Try this:

```
$('.carousel-content').carouFredSel({
    circular: false,
    infinite: false,
    auto: false,
    align: 'left',
    width: 940,
    height: 323,
    scroll: 1,
    items: 4,
    onCreate: function() {
      $('#xy.concat(carousel_count) >  .caroufredsel_wrapper.concat(carousel_count)').css('float','left');
    }},
    {
    wrapper: { 
      element:'div',
      classname: 'caroufredsel_wrapper.concat(carousel_count)'
    });
```